# Domain of a trig function (GRE)

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Suppose that the function *f* is defined on an interval by the formula $$f(x)=\sqrt{\tan^2( x) - 1}$$. If *f* is continuous which of the following intervals could be its domain?

1. $(3π/4, π)$
2. $(π/4, π/2)$
3. $(π/4, 3π/4)$
4. $(-π/4, 0)$
5. $(-3π/4, -π/4)$

Comment: do you mean $$\sqrt{\tan(x)^2-1}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner expressed tan^2(x) as 1/(cos^2(x)) -1, then cos^2(x) != 0 and 1/(cos^2(x)) -1>=0. And then stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: and write you inequation in the form $$(\tan(x)-1)(\tan(x)+1)\geq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Solve the inequation $$\tan^2(x)\geq 1.$$